# In JavaFX 2.1 button image is not shown

Tags: javafx-2

JavaFX 2.1:

My button with image works fine in JavaFX 2.0. Upgrade to JavaFX 2.1, the image disappeared.

Here is the code:

```
Button aButton = new Button("Test");
String iconPath = "/com/abc/res/toolbar/Help.gif";
Image aIcon = new Image(
    getClass().getResourceAsStream(iconPath), 18, 18, false, false);
aButton.setGraphic(new ImageView(aIcon));
```

This works under JavaFX 2.0. It doesn't work under JavaFX 2.1. To make the graphic shows up, I have to remove the re-size function.

```
Image aIcon = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(iconPath));
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button graphic not showing up for the resized image would appear to be a regression - to get it fixed, file a bug to http://javafx-jira.kenai.com with your sample code and sample image.

As a workaround, load the Image without resizing it in the constructor and resize the loaded image in an `ImageView` via `imageView.fitWidth()` and `imageView.fitHeight()`.

Comment: imageView.fitWidth() works.                                  aImageView.setFitHeight(18);
aImageView.setFitWidth(18);---Thanks